# How to fix dlib.full_object_detection callable object not being callable so several numpy arrays can be saved to a npz file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dlib, callable

I am trying to save multiple numpy arrays that contain 68 facial landmark coordinates from images. I am using .format at the end of the name of the array, however when I run the program in terminal, it returns with object not callable.

I am on raspberrypi3 running raspbian, and am using this program for emotion recognition using facial landmarks with OpenCV, dlib, and python. The code I am using is modded and inserted code from pyimagesearch's face recognition pages, plus some of my own code. I tried putting the .format line with line 43, however it returned with

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

```
#import the necessary packages  
from imutils import face_utils  
from imutils import paths  
import numpy as np  
import argparse  
import imutils  
import dlib  
import cv2  
import os  
#construct the argument parser and parse the arguments  
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()  
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,  
            help="path to facial landmark predictor")  
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,  
            help="path to input image")  
args = vars(ap.parse_args())  

#grab path to images that are being converted  
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["image"]))  
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):  
    print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}".format(i + 1,  
        len(imagePaths)))  
    #load the input image, and convert it to grayscale  
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)  
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)  
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  

    #detect faces in the grayscale  
    rects = detector(gray, 1)  

    #loop over the face detections  
    for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):  
        #determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then  
        #convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy  
        #array  
        shape = predictor(gray, rect)  
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape("{}".format[i] for i in   
        imagePaths))  

        #save the numpy array  
        for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):  
            np.savez("arrays.npz", shape)  
            shape_npz = np.load("arrays.npz")  
            d = dict(zip(("data1{}".format(k) for k in shape_npz),  
            (shape_npz[k] for k in shape_npz)))
```

When I ran the code in terminal, it came out with

```
TypeError: 'dlib.full_object_detection' object is not callable
```

However, when I ran callable on it, it came back with

```
True
```

I expected the output to be

```
[INFO] processing image 1/4  
[INFO] processing image 2/4  
[INFO] processing image 3/4  
[INFO] processing image 4/4
```

with each picture's numpy array in between.
How can I fix it so it saves each numpy array to the array.npz file?

Comment: You import `dlib`, but the code sample does not create or use `dlib.full_object_detection`.  If fact it doesn't use `dlib` at all.  In any case the error says that it is a `ndarray`, and not a function (callable).  `x()` is the syntax that tries to use `x` as a callable.  `x[...]` is indexing syntax, and words on an `ndarray`.